# Vuejs - Update Object in an Array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using VueJs and I have an array of objects. What i want to do is update an object in the array based on its index. For that I've written a method:

```
updateRow(index) {
      this.inputs[index]={ "one": "test", "two": "test" }
    }
```

However, the object just doesn't update. I've created the following jsbin for it.

https://jsbin.com/boturuluxe/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:

1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue
2. When you modify the length of the array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength

The solution is:
`this.$set(this.inputs, index, { "one": "test", "two": "test" })`

[Read more here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
updateRow(index) {
  Vue.set(this.inputs, index, { "one": "test", "two": "test" })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
updateRow(index) {
  this.inputs[index]={ "one": "test", "two": "test" };
  this.inputs = Object.assign({}, this.inputs);
  // assigning a new object reference
}
```

Or,

```js
updateRow(index) {
  this.$set(this.inputs, index, { "one": "test", "two": "test" });
}
```

[Vue docs reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)